# AFrame - Rotation of a-camera entity continuously 60 degrees at a time

Tags: javascript, aframe

My use case is to rotate camera 60 degree at a time depending on user swipe left or right. So I decide to try it with a-animation. I could drag the camera around like a-videosphere or a-sky and when I swipe it will spin 60 degrees and stop and I could continue swiping left or right, which move 60 degree, plus dragging the camera.

I would also like to see if I can get `ease` effect on the look-control if possible, couldn't find anything related online.

I tried:

1)  Setting the animation direction `normal` and `reverse` dynamically based on the mousedown and mouseup position, but it always spin one direction based on the initial value.

2) I tried binding the `from` and `to`, and set the `from` of the animation based on the rotation value of the a) `vr-camera` and b) `camera-wrapper` and set the `to` of the animation to `camera.x camera.y + (+/-60degree) camera.z`.  But animation always reset to the original position and start from that point and ignore the `from` value even the DOM is updated.

3) I tried to rotate the `vr-camera` without wrapper, and `camera-wrapper` but both reset the rotation to the original point.

4) I tried to `look-controls="enabled: false"` on the camera, this remove the dragging of the camera but the swipe still reset from original position.

```js
      handleMouseDown(e) {
        console.log("mousedown");
        document.querySelector('a-animation').stop();
        this.mousedownPosition = { x: e.x, y: e.y };
      },
      handleMouseUp(e) {
        console.log("mouseup");
        this.mouseupPosition = { x: e.x, y: e.y };

        const direction = this.mousedownPosition.x > this.mouseupPosition.x ? 60 : -60;
       
        debugger;
        const cameraRotation = document.getElementById('camera-wrapper').getAttribute('rotation')
        this.fromRotation = `${cameraRotation.x} ${cameraRotation.y} ${cameraRotation.z}`;

        const yRotation = cameraRotation.y + direction;
        this.toRotation = `${cameraRotation.x} ${yRotation} ${cameraRotation.z}`;

       
        // Make sure DOM is updated before emit event 
        this.$nextTick(function () {
          document.getElementById('camera-wrapper').emit('swipe');
        });

       },
```

```html
<a-scene  id="aframescene" class="aframebox" vr-mode-ui="enabled: false" embedded physics="gravity: 0;" debug>
        <a-entity id="camera-wrapper">
          <!--<a-camera id="vr-camera" look-controls="enabled: false" fov="60" easing="ease-in-out"> </a-camera>-->
          <a-camera id="vr-camera" look-controls="reverseMouseDrag: true" fov="60" easing="ease-in-out"> </a-camera>
          <a-animation
            id="swipe"
            :from="fromRotation"
            :to="toRotation"
            attribute="rotation"
            direction="normal"
            begin="swipe"
            dur="4000"
            repeat="0"
            easing="ease-in-out">
          </a-animation>        
        </a-entity>

        <a-assets timeout="1">
          <video id="videoid" crossorigin="anonymous" src="video.src" type="video/mp4" webkit-playsinline playsinline ></video>
          <img id="imageid" crossorigin="anonymous" src="image.src"></img>
        </a-assets>

        <!-- Handle both image and video as src -->
        <a-entity id="sky" geometry="primitive: sphere; radius: 100"
                  :material="src: #imageid;  side:front; color:#FFF; shader:flat; npot:true'"
                  scale="-1 1 1">
        </a-entity>   
      </a-scene>
```

After the animation ran: The rotation value of camera-wrapper is `0 60 0`, where I expected it to be `0 0 0`, which is the same as the `to` value of the animation.

[image]

Comment: FYI, the DOM element attributes don't update unless you have the debug attribute set on the scene: ```<a-scene debug>```

Comment: Yes, I do have the debug on.  But what I meant was the value of from and to are being altered before the event was emit.   I am starting to think that dynamic update of a-animation is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to use aframe-animation-component to bind the from and to values at run time.

```js
require('aframe-animation-component');



      const scene = document.querySelector('a-scene');
      scene.addEventListener('mousedown', this.handleMouseDown);
      scene.addEventListener('mouseup', this.handleMouseUp);
      
      handleMouseDown(e) {
        this.mousedownPosition = { x: e.x, y: e.y };
      },
      handleMouseUp(e) {
        this.mouseupPosition = { x: e.x, y: e.y };
        const direction = this.mousedownPosition.x > this.mouseupPosition.x ? 60 : -60;

        const cameraRotation = document.getElementById('camera-wrapper').getAttribute('rotation')
        this.fromRotation = `${cameraRotation.x} ${cameraRotation.y} ${cameraRotation.z}`;

        const yRotation = cameraRotation.y + direction;
        this.toRotation = `${cameraRotation.x} ${yRotation} ${cameraRotation.z}`;


        // Make sure DOM is updated before emit event
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          document.getElementById('camera-wrapper').emit('swipe');
        });
      },
```

```html
<a-scene  id="aframescene" class="aframebox" vr-mode-ui="enabled: false" embedded physics="gravity: 0; debug: true" debug>
        <a-entity id="camera-wrapper"
                  :animation__rotation="`property: rotation; dir: normal; dur: 1000; startEvents:swipe ;
                  easing: easeInSine; from:${fromRotation}; to:${toRotation}`">
          <a-camera id="vr-camera" universal-controls look-controls="{enable: false}" fov="60"></a-camera>
        </a-entity>
         
        <!-- below replace a-videosphere and a-sky for video and image -->
        <a-entity id="sky" geometry="primitive: sphere; radius: 100"
                  :material="'src: ' + currentSource +'; side:front; color:#FFF; shader:flat; npot:true'"
                  scale="-1 1 1">
        </a-entity>
      </a-scene>
```